# Insert 'select all' choice in a particular level in Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm using D7. And I have a big term reference tree with Term Reference Tree. There are so many terms in the tree that I'd like to put 'select all' choice in it for usability.
Is it possible to put 'select all' choice in some level?

Let me show you the example of what I want to do below...

(Ex)
Let's say there is a vocabulary whose name is 'Food'

**[Food]**

**-Vegetable**
--Select All
--Pumpkin
--Carrot
--Radish
--Potato
**-Fruit**
**-Fish**

So, what I want to do is...if you check the 'Select All' under the Vegetable level, the all of choices(Pumpkin, Carrot, Radish, Potato) will be checked.

I searched the way to do that but couldn't find the answer. Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Added:**
I found you can do something like I want to do by the setting below...
-Start minimized =>Whichever
-Leaves only =>Off
-Select parents automatically =>On
-Cascading selection =>On

With the setting above, you can chose all choices by checking the parent level.
**But, I also wanted to enforce users to chose the deepest level.**
With the setting above, users don't always have to chose the deepest level...
So, correctly, I'd like to say I want to put 'select all' and enforce users chose the deepest level.
I still need your help. Thank you.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan OP is asking about in particular with taxonomy and selecting all taxonomy terms under a parent.. I believe it's not a duplicate question..

Comment: @KrishnaMohan as @ Anil Sagar says I wanted to ask the way about selecting all choices under a particular parent(on the example above, if you check 'select all' on Vegetable, you will only check the choices under it. so you don't check any choices under Fruit nor Fish). The way you pasted is for selecting all choices in the vocabulary, right? Sorry that my question seemed confusing...

Comment: When you say "enforce users chose the deepest level", do you mean that you do not want the parent (e.g. Vegetable) to be selectable?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal have [Taxonomy Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) module where all levels and terms have checkbox options and also **add, edit, delete, move,** functionality here.

**Taxonomy Manager:**

> This module provides a powerful interface for managing taxonomies. A vocabulary gets displayed in a dynamic tree view, where parent terms can be expanded to list their nested child terms or can be collapsed.
>
> For using the [Taxonomy Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) you should have JavaScript and automatically load of images enabled in your browser.